# Get substring between 2 certain characters

Tags: jquery, substring

For example I have this string:

```
via_route_1;via_route_2;via_route_4;via_route_7;
```

And I supply to the function the number (eg. 4), then how can I get the substring `;via_route_4` ?

My aim is to delete a substring, depending on the number that I supply.

I know how to get the index of 4, for example, but how to go backwards until I find the first `;` and then take that whole substring thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like that? Using no custom functions just manipulating the string.

```
/* your string */
var s = "via_route_1;via_route_2;via_route_4;via_route_7;";

/* index of 4 */
var i1 = s.indexOf("4");

/* substring from first character to the 4 (including the number) */
var sub1 = s.substring(1, i1 + 1);

/* last index of ; in substring */
var i2 = sub1.lastIndexOf(";");

/* new substring starting with ; */
var sub2 = sub1.substring(i2, sub1.length);
console.log(sub2);
```

Logs `;via_route_4`.

Comment: Aha! `lastIndexOf` kind of logic was what I did not think of. Nice one! And, btw, my point was simply string manipulation anyways, so - perfect answer! :)